# The pipe 'currency' could not be found (AOT)

Tags: angular

We have an angular that we upgraded from angular 6 to 7. where we are using the build-in `currency` pipe. Everything works fine when serving (`ng serve`) and when building in DEV.

But when we try to build in **production** we are getting `The pipe 'currency' could not be found`. Actually none of the pipes are working anymore. The same error is displayed.

The issue did **not** happen in version 6.

**EDIT**

I am getting the same error with `ng build --aot`

Comment: what are doing to make a production build?

Comment: @AkshayM `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --extract-css --configuration=production && npm run generate-config`

Comment: Try running `ng build --prod`. It may not be enough considering your requirements,  but check if this helps to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @AkshayM, I get the same error using `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 4):

I have found the issue.

We had `enableIvy` set to true in tsconfig.json. It was tree tree shaking away the pipes.

Comment: As of May 2019 this still an open issue with Ivy, the new Angular compiler: see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436