# Angular 7 doesn't find pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, web, angular7, angular-pipe

I'm trying to build my Angular 7 project but every time I get an error saying

> Template parse errors: The pipe 'currency' could not be found.

But when I try to run the `ng serve` it does works as expected

I've tried to build it with the `--prod` flag, and it doesn't work. If I remove the production flag, it builds correctly.

Comment: Did you add the pipe to the `declarations`/`export` of the module(s) you're using it in?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53259307/1009922) may help you.

Comment: Actually I found another solution for the problem, there is something wrong with the AOT, I had to disable AOT and Build Optimizer wit hthe flags `--prod --aot false --build-optimizer false` and it worked

Comment: That is not really a solution. The fact you see this error must mean something is wrong with the import of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use pipes, you first need add pipe to your module declarations:

```
import {CurrencyPipeComponent}  from './currencypipe.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      ...,
  declarations: [
                 ...,
                 CurrencyPipeComponent],
})
export class YourModuleWhichYourComponentIsRegistered { }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
in `tsconfig.json` change

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
}
```

for

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not too helpful, please explain why it would work.