# How do I display a date in Angular 7 using DatePipe

Tags: angular

I took over an Angular 5 code base from a previous employee, and very recently went through an involved process to bring it up to date with Angular 7.

The code is deployed in both a development and production environment to Netlify. The build commands I use for both environments are as follows.

For dev: `ng build --prod=false --configuration=staging`

For prod: `ng build --prod=true --configuration=production`

When I deploy to dev, there are no problems. The app builds without issue and performs as expected.

This morning, for the first time since the major version upgrade, I am deploying to prod. The build on Netlify is failing with an error that seems odd to me.

```
The pipe 'date' could not be found ("
  <h4>Token Expiration</h4>
  <pre>{{[ERROR ->]expiresAt | date:'medium'}}</pre>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
"): /opt/build/repo/src/app/token/token.component.html@13:9
```

The `expiresAt` method is in `token.component.ts` and is super simple:

```
get expiresAt() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
}
```

In `token.component.html` the display of the token expiration is also pretty straightforward:

```
<h4>Token Expiration</h4>
<pre>{{expiresAt | date:'medium'}}</pre>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this build is failing and displaying this error for prod but not for dev?

Comment: did you import `CommonModule` in a module that declares this component?

Comment: Please add your expiresAt variable output.

Comment: @shadowman_93 Mar 8, 2019, 10:18:57 AM is an example of what is displayed when expiresAt is called.

Comment: Hmmm, can you please add your webpack.config files? So we can see the difference for each builds...

Comment: There are similar issue reported when new Ive engine is turned on. Do you have it maybe enabled too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503724/angular-7-doesnt-find-pipes

Comment: Borys, thank you very much! That was the issue. I set enableIvy to false, and the build worked just fine. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have the new Angular rendering engine enabled (Ivy) that may have an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436) atm with Pipes in AOT mode.

Check if you have it enabled in `tsconfig.json`, and turn it off for the time:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

Comment: Special thanks to Borys Kupar. All is well after setting enableIvy to false.

Comment: I'm developing Angular almost 1 year and first time see this kind of issue :)